# Jvm Not found Please Install 32 bit sdk?

Tags: java, android, jvm

I have to check my Ionic app in android. 
I have installed Android SDK and Java JDK and set all Environment-Variable.

But my Android SDK is showing following error: 
`JVM not found install 32 bit version`

I have searched for android 32 bit version, but I couldn't find it any where ?

My Os is a 32 bit version

Comment: Maybe missing the java /bin directory on your path?https://java.com/en/download/help/path.xml

Comment: i have added path C:\Program Files\Java\jdk\bin.. now my question android sdk 64 bit  its work or not in windows 32 bit system?

Comment: Seems like you installed the 64-Bit JDK instead of the 32-Bit one?
I allways had to restart Windows when installing JDK, even with the path set right!

Comment: i have searching i couldn't find any where 32 bit sdk even i searched   http://developer.android.com/ here also but there 64 bit only. i cant find out 32 bit version

Answer (score 0):

If you have 32 bit operation system you need to install java jdk as x86 version for example : http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html choose  Java SE Development Kit 8u45 x86 version of you OS

Set Environment variable to this version and restart OS